# PHP foreach((array)) behavior

Tags: php, foreach

I have come across a PHP foreach statement that I am having trouble finding any documentation on.

Here is the code I am having trouble understanding:

```
<?php foreach((array)$this->item->partno as $value): ?>
    // do some stuff
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

What is the (array) doing and what is happening with this foreach?

Comment: It is just saying the item is an array and the foreach is getting a value from the array on each iteration.

Comment: Seems like a basic search could have helped here.

Comment: @Adam - not if you don't know what the terminology is. What should he search for if he doesn't know what it's called?

Comment: @Utkanos - if you understand basics of programming, you could understand this is casting an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This technique is useful when you have a function and you want it to take an argument that can be either a single value or an array. For example, you might normally do something like this:

```
function foo($items) {
    if (!is_array($items)) {
        $items = array($items);
    }
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

By casting the variable to an array inline, you can avoid the explicit array check, and the code will work fine if you pass it either a single value or an array:

```
function foo($items) {
    foreach ((array) $items as $item) {
        // ...
    }
}
foo(1);
foo([1, 2, 3]);
```

Answer (score 3):

You're casting (converting) whatever the type of `$this->item->partno` is, in an array.

More on this in the php docs [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php)